# How to release seemingly inactive executors from a long-running PySpark framework?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Here's my problem. Let's say I have a long-running PySpark framework. It has thousands of tasks that can all be executed in parallel. I get allocated 1,000 cores at the beginning on many different hosts. Each task needs one core. Then, when those finish, the host holds onto one core and has no active tasks. Since there are a large number of hosts, what can happen is that a larger and larger percentage of my cores are allocated to executors that don't have any active tasks. So I can have 1000 cores allocated, but only 100 active tasks. The other 900 cores are allocated to executors that have no active tasks. How can I improve this? Is there a way to shut down executors that aren't doing anything? I am currently using PySpark 1.2, so it'd be great for the functionality to be in that version, but would be happy to hear about solutions (or better solutions) in newer versions. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a resource manager? Or Spark standalone?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify the number of executors that Spark should use, Spark allocates executors as long as Spark has at least 1 task pending in its queue. You can set an upper limit to the number of executors that Spark can dynamically allocate by using this parameter: `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors`.

In other word, when launching spark, use:
`pyspark --master yarn-client --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=1000`
instead of 
`pyspark --master yarn-client --num-executors=1000`

By default, Spark will release executors after `60s` of non-activity.

Note, if you `.persist()` your Spark.DataFrame, make sure to `.unpersist()` them otherwise Spark will not release the executors.

Comment: Note that QA didn't specify that they were using YARN.